# Do I need to implement onSave/restoreInstance in the parent view too?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view:  `class MyView extends LinearLayout` etc that has as member variables e.g. children another custom view.
I have implemented in the child custom view the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` but I noticed that they are not being called when I put the app in the background.
Would I need to implement those in the parent view `MyView` as well?

Comment: Just implement them for any of your custom view.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam: But is the parent view supposed to call the `onSaveInstance` of the child view? How should I do it?

Comment: hey I suggest you read this, quite useful http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/

Answer (score 0):

If you have already implemented `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` for your view.

You need to make sure that your custom view has an ID, if `View.getId()` method returns an ID that is not > 0, state of that view will not be saved nor restored.

You can set that ID through XML `android:id` or programatically `View.setID()`

Comment: That child view has an id. Are you referring to the parent view?